# why xmlHttp can't be opened?

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get some information from outer server and perform the following:

```
var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();
xmlHttp.open("GET", url + "?wsdl", async);
```

where xmlHTTP contents:

```
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload:  null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: null
ontimeout: null
readyState: 1
response: ""
responseText: ""
responseType:""
responseURL: ""
responseXML: null
status: 0
statusText: ""
timeout: 0
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload
withCredentials: false
__proto__: XMLHttpRequest
```

and SOAPClient._getXmlHttp that has returned preveous XMLHttpRequest is

```
function() 
{
    try
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();             
            if(req.readyState == null) 
            {
                req.readyState = 1;
                req.addEventListener("load", 
                                    function() 
                                    {
                                        req.readyState = 4;
                                        if(typeof req.onreadystatechange == "function")
                                            req.onreadystatechange();
                                    },
                                    false);
            }
            return req;
        }
        if(window.ActiveXObject) 
            return new ActiveXObject(SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID());
    }
    catch (ex) {}
    throw new Error("Your browser does not support XmlHttp objects");
}
```

so finally trying to open xmlHttp I get the following:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

`async` is `false`

**UPD**:

I guess it can't get wsdl but as far as I'm stupid in js I can't figure out if I'm right cuz `xmlHttp.responseXML` has nothing I expected based on my experience of working with soap and wsdl as well. And so finally I get internal server error although when I use SoapUI I get wsdl and get methods which works well

**UPD1**: Here is the extended code of function sending request:

```
var ns = (wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"] + "" == "undefined") ? wsdl.documentElement.attributes.getNamedItem("targetNamespace").nodeValue : wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"].value;
    // build SOAP request
    var sr = "soap request here";
    // send request
    var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();                     
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, async);
    var soapaction = ((ns.lastIndexOf("/") != ns.length - 1) ? ns + "/" : ns) + method;
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", soapaction);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    xmlHttp.send(sr);
```

the soap request is correct, being executed with SoapUI returns correct data, but being processed from my js app it gives an exception

> OPTIONS https:'https adress' 500 (Internal
>   server error)SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest @
>   soapclient.js:198SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl @
>   soapclient.js:162SOAPClient._loadWsdl @
>   soapclient.js:156SOAPClient.invoke @ soapclient.js:129Adapter.query
>   @ adapter.js:108Model.findAll @ model.js:49Organisation.init @
>   organisation.js:8(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.js:14each @
>   jquery.min.js:2each @ jquery.min.js:2(anonymous function) @
>   bootstrap.js:9j @ jquery.min.js:2fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2ready @
>   jquery.min.js:2K @ jquery.min.js:2

it's clear that main part of that text notes to places in my js app, but does

> OPTIONS https:'https adress' 500 (Internal
>   server error)

I've found that the possible solution is to change Apache's httpd.conf (where the outer server is) and instead of

> AllowOverride All
>    Options None

for current domain, to

> AllowOverride All
>    Options All

but this didn't help.

Comment: The warning is very clear: using `async = false` is deprecated. Fix your code to work asynchronously.

Comment: Put the warning message into the Search field and you'll find many previous questions explaining it.

Comment: Why do you think it can't be opened? This is just a warning, it doesn't prevent using it.

Comment: @Barmar I guess it can't get wsdl but as far as I'm stupid in js I can't figure out if I'm right cuz xmlHttp.responseXML has nothing I expected based on my experience of working with soap and wsdl as well. And so finally I get internal server error although when I use SoapUI I get wsdl and get methods which works well

Comment: The problem may be with the parameters you're sending when you call `xmlhttp.send()`.